# Joomla component not found

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.5

I have a site with a really old version of Joomla, upgrade it or not is not my decision, so I have to work with this version (1.5.15). 
The problem is on the site, the home page it's ok, loads all css and js, but when I access to another menu item I get: **404 Component not found**, but the component exists, and also the url to access to resoruces (css, img, js, etc) is not correct, for example this is the url www.mypage.com, the url of resources is like `/plugins/system/rokbox/themes/light/rokbox-style.css`, when I access to another menu item the url is like `www.mypage.com/index.php/resource_location`. 
What can I do? Why is this happening?

Comment: Has this problem occurred recently or has it always been a problem. If recently, then what changes have been made to the site that could have caused it? I.e installation of any plugins, core code changes etc

Comment: Can't you at least update to 1.5.26? if you haven't performed recent activity it's quite likely you were attacked

Comment: @Lodder this problem ocurred recently. I'm researching if someone made changes, I'm not the admin of the site, but I have to fix their mistakes.

Comment: @RiccardoZorn I'm trying to convince my boss to upgrade. Hope it works.

Comment: Ahh ok. It is quite possible that some changes might have been made to the htaccess file, a SEF component was installed, or there is some plugin manipulation. If this is a live site, then the word "security" should convince you boss to atleast upgrade to Joomla 1.5.26

Comment: Also check to see if php was upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to consider:

1. Someone made a mistake: and changed the SEF configuration, maybe they just disabled SEF or routing or changed the .htaccess;
2. Someone attacked your site: pretty easy with your Joomla version.

In either case if you lack documentation or information you need to explore the differences, just load a working backup on a folder i.e. working_backup on the same server and run a diff:

```
diff -qrwbBE working_backup public_html
```

This will give you a list of different files, if there are none, go check the plugin configuration maybe a plugin was disabled such as SEF, else open them and see what changed.

If you do not have a working backup, download Joomla 1.5.15 from the [Joomla version history site](http://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_1.5_version_history) and run the same command, you will get a longer list including any 3rd party extensions; but it's reasonable that the issue lies with core Joomla or a SEF extension, it will be easy to pick it up.

Remember to clear the cache: the error may no longer be there but be cached, and the site might lack permissions to update the cache.